# Ubuntu boot USB flash does not work

Tags: installation, boot, usb, live-usb, syslinux

MY laptop is a Dell Inspiron 5520 with a sticker of Ubuntu on it. i have downloaded Ubuntu desktop 12.10 64-bit and made my Ubuntu bootable USB flash drive. I restarted my computer. It gave a black screen with one line begins with:

```
syslinux 4.06 --- 1992 - 2012
```

And then there was no response. How can I fix this and get the Ubuntu flash drive to boot?

Answer (score 0):

I read on the [Dell Inspiron 5520 Ubuntu certification page](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201201-10377/) that:

> Standard images of Ubuntu may not work at all on the system or may not work well, though Canonical and computer manufacturers will try to certify the system with future standard releases of Ubuntu.

On the other hand, if you laptop came with 12.04 pre-installed, why not try upgrade the system with `do-release-upgrade`?